# What is the benefit for me to offer bounty on another person's question?

Tags: discussion

What is the benefit for me to offer bounty on another person's question? Will it increase my reputation also?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> What is the benefit for me to offer bounty on another person's
>   question?

It gets the question more attention, hopefully getting the OP (and you!) more and better answers. This is the recommended course of action when you have a question that is a duplicate of an existing one; rather than opening a new question you can offer some bounty to get more eyes on the previous one.

You can also get badges, for the first one you [offer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/219/investor) and the first one you [award](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/222/altruist), which you may or may not consider much of a benefit!

> Will it increase my reputation also?

No, it **costs** you reputation: *"It is funded by the personal reputation of the user who offers it, and is **non-refundable**."*

I suggest you read the relevant [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) and [privilege page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties).